# How install wordpress in another wordpress folder?

Tags: multisite, apache

I have a [wordpress](https://wordpress.org/) site(`example.com`) and I want to run another wordpress on the server. `example.com`'s files are at `/var/www/html/example.com` directory on the server. I created a `anotherSite` Folder in `/var/www/html/example.com/anotherSite` and then copy all wordpress files in it. When I run `http://example.com/anotherSite`, It connect to `anotherSite` but then redirect to `http://example.com/anothersite-how-can-we-have/23023`.

`/var/www/html/example.com/.htaccess` are as follow:

```
########## REDIRECT SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

####### REDIRECT WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 /MYFolder(.*) /MYFolder/$1


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I fix redirect?

**Note**: `example.com` have a post with id `23023` and title `anothersite-how-can-we-have`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but If you change folder of wordpress installation and when URL visited it still shows old URL, but you want it to show new URL. You should change address in wordpress settings.

Instructions:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL